# Can't run a wifi hotspot via my laptop

Tags: wireless, laptop, connection, hot-spot

I tried to create a wifi hotspot from my laptop(connected to a wired broadband connection). I followed instructions from various tutorials, but i think that the OS cannot recognize my wifi lan adaptor. All is well it says that it's connected and running but when i scan with my android phone ican't find my hostpot.Also,my laptop dose not see Any wifi networks, event tough my phone can see several in the area.

Answer (score 2):

Wifi hotspot isn't same as wireless ad hoc networks. Most android device doesn't support wi-fi in adhoc mode. What you are running is simply an ad hoc network.

For running your laptop as an access point, this is only possible if your wireless adapter supports going into the `master mode`. or if the driver for wireless is a mac80211 based driver. If it does not support either one, you're totally out of luck.

Its very tough to setup even if it supports. First you need to setup wireless card and then set up a dhcp server (to get dhcp server up and running is really a horrible task)

How to test `master mode` and configure access point

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/MasterMode

Helpful threads to setup wireless access point

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=376283

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663788

Comment: You don't necessarily need a DHCP server if all of the OP's devices can be comfigured with a manual IP address. I would use for the host: `IP: 192.168.2.1 Gateway: 127.0.0.1(Or your wired router's IP) DNS servers: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4` and for the guests: `IP: 192.168.2.[something unique from 2 to 200], Gateway 192.168.2.1, DNS servers 8.8.8.8, .8.84.4`.